# [X-Ray for Jira][Configuration error]: "view-issue-section.error.custom-fields-not-configured.title"

Tags: test-management

After getting our Jira admin to setup X-Ray for Jira - there is problem, when I create a X-Ray "Test".
In the "Test Details" section, we get this error message:
" view-issue-section.error.custom-fields-not-configured.title" 
"view-issue-section.error.custom-fields-not-configured.message" (see also attached image)
I hope someone here might have had a similar experience and know what to check.

Thanks,
Jesper
[image]

Comment: What is a final solution to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Xray presents that error message when its needed Jira custom fields aren't setup.

The vendor has a knowledge base article that addresses this: https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/ProductKB/%5BXray+Server%5D+Xray+Custom+Fields+Not+Configured

Hope this helps!